# Using ng-If with ng-repeat for hiding unvisible items when displaying big collection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a big collection of items - ~2000 items.

When displaying with ng-repeat, the number of watchers is 16K and the DOM is barely alive.

I am trying to display the items in a table using ng-if, so that only visible items would be visible.

I have tried to implement infinite scrolling, but it does not solve the huge number of watchers. So I decided that it would be best if I just won't render the elements which are not visible.

Is there a query which I can put on every element that will fast tell me if the item is visible on the page?

My Code is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="mi in vm.displayDNAList track by $index">
 <span>{{ ::mi.name }}</span>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi  ;) Please mark the answer that helped you the most as the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With vast collections of items that render many DOM elements, even the most negligible processing of items inside an `ng-repeat` can choke your app.
DOM-related solutions that check if elements are in view don't tell you if nested components have been loaded and rendered completely, leading to errors.

My solution to this problem is Angular's limitTo : limit: begin filter, along with iScroll or native scrollTop and scrollBottom callbacks, which raise or reduce the begin index in the controller according to the browse direction - sort of frontend pagination where only a specific number of items are shown at the DOM.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo : 100 : 600 track by $index">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</tr>
```

You need to find the optimal `limitTo` number that works best for the app  while keeping it light and agile.

Comment: How can I send calc method the table's element for calculating the scrollTop value? something like - ng-if = "calc(??)" - can work?

Comment: Listen to the native `scroll` event and fire functions, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w7x9n/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter to limit the results to only the visible elements.This assumes that the mi object has a property called visible.

```
<tr ng-repeat="mi in vm.displayDNAList | filter:visible track by $index">
 <span>{{ ::mi.name }}</span>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use filter in javascript before using ng-repeat

```
vm.displayDNAList = data.filter(function(d){
  return d.element;
});
```

if you want to use ng-if it will still go throw the each element rendering will become slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="mi in vm.displayDNAList track by $index">
 <span id="{{mi.name}}">{{ ::mi.name }}</span>
</tr>
```

in JS check if the ID is present in DOM using

```
if(document.getElementById(value)!==undefined){
return true;
}
```

This is fast. But you can also try do a filter and write a function which returns a boolean. This may or may not work depending on use case.

```
function valueCheckerFunction(item){
    if(item==='xx'){
        return item;
    }
}
    return if(vm.displayDNAList.filter(valuecheckerFunction));
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: ng-repeat put all ID's in the DOM already. I need to figure out a way to check if the ID is currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create an array of element you want to display seperately and render on that array. instead of using limit or filter because it will icrese your dom only thing is that it will not be visible.

```
mainArray= [2000 element];
createAnArray = [25elements]
```

change that createAnArray variable as you want depending on events

Comment: I am missing the event. How would I know I've reached to the 25th element and I need to show the next 25?

Comment: there will be array initially of 25 elements. There will be one button called load more. then you append next 25 elements to that array and so on

Comment: I would like to do without the need of clicking a button

Comment: do you mean on scrolling? You can do it.